# iReport xls export exclude detail bands?

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, export

I am currently using iReports 5.1.0.

I been experimenting with the format export properties to modify the report based on what it is being exported as.

properties similar to...

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.phase" value="groupHeader"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.group.phase" value="Phase"/>
```

I figured out how to work every band in the report based on the export at runtime. However, I can't figure out how to do this with detail bands.

If i had one detail band i could do it like this...

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.detail1" value="detail"/>
```

However, I have 3 different detail bands. I would need the first detail band to be excluded when exported to excel. Then I would need to have only the first detail band 2 to show. I looked all over the documentation and can't seem to find any info on achieving this with the method above.

I know that I can use the print when expression, but I prefer to do this approach if it is possible.

Here are my report properties...

```
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.freeze.row" value="0"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.freeze.column" value="0"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.title" value="title"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.group" value="groupHeader"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.group.group" value="Group"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.phase" value="groupHeader"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.group.phase" value="Phase"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.detail1" value="detail"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.footer" value="pageFooter"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.image.border.fix.enabled" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.column.width.ratio" value="1.10f"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.graphics" value="false"/>
<property name="ireport.database" value="jdbc/DriverB"/>
<property name="ireport.displayTitle" value="CDP Follow Up"/>
<property name="ireport.category" value="test"/>
<property name="ireport.defaultExport" value="pdf"/>
```

My question is, how can I conditionally print specific detail bands based on the export type instead of using a print when expression on the detail band?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: My question is, how can I conditionally print specific detail bands based on the export type instead of using a print when expression on the detail band?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for this is:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.{format}.exclude.origin.{suffix}.{arbitrary_name}
```

Read more details here:
[JasperReports - Configuration Reference](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html)

Concrete examples would be:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.1=pageHeader
net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.2=detail1
```

Comment: That's the problem I am having. net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.2=detail1 doesn't exclude detail line 1 when exporting to excel.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't realize that you've used detail1 as your arbitrary name. I've never excluded a detail band for specific exporters, only header or footer bands or worked with printWhenExpression to hide detail bands.

Comment: Maybe it isn't even possible to exlude a specific detail band as all detail bands are within one xml node and don't have a unique id or name.

Comment: trieber I believe you may be correct. I will result to using a print when expression on the line and setting a parameter at run time of the export format.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the export type (ex: csv, pdf) as parameter to the .jrxml file. In the jrxml create a field for the passed parameter. In the "print when expression" section, add condition to exclude the details band that need not be exported for a requested export type.
Ex:

```
parameterMap.put("type","xls");
```

print when expression:`!$F{type}.equals("xls")`