# Jasper Reports add column on xls export

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have a report using 9 fields while 1 is used for a group header. Can I move a group header into the last column (add other fields loaded from query) when exporting to xls?

Comment: You can use different bands (with dfferent layout, for example) for different output formats. These posts can help you: [iReport xls export exclude detail bands?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22204417/876298) & [jasper report export excel without page header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34781152/876298)

Comment: Can I also set a detail to print in an exported xls file, but don't print it in the Jasper Report?  I've not found anything on the ŕeference page, neither on any forum.